# Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j Issue

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am writing Junits to test my logs. I am using LogCaptor. I have attached my actual method and my testcases along with pom.xml.

This is my method where i have logs defined.

```
@Override
public ApplicationResponse createApplication (final String serviceId, final String appId) throws KMSException     {
    log.debug("Entering createApplication");
    try {
        final Application application =
            applicationOperations.createApplication(appId, serviceId);
        return applicationResponse(application);
    }
    catch (KMSCommonException exception) {
        throw new KMSInternalServerErrorException("Not able to create application", exception);
    }
}
```

This is my `test method` to test Loggers :

```
@Test
public void testCreateApplicationLogger () throws KMSException {
    String expectedInfoMessage = "Entering createApplication";

    LogCaptor logCaptor = LogCaptor.forClass(Test.class);
    adminAPIApplicationOpService.createApplication(TEST_SERVICE, TEST_APP + 1);
    assertTrue( logCaptor.getInfoLogs().contains(expectedInfoMessage));

}
```

Comment: how does your pom.xml looks like ?

Comment: @CKey I have added pom.xml please have a look. Thanks

Comment: i just looked into the official site: [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/)


there you can see that 

"Use of the Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding (**log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar**) together with the SLF4J adapter (**log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.jar**) should never be attempted, as it will cause events to endlessly be routed between SLF4J and Log4j 2."

so, probably it works, if you 1. figure out in the maven dependencies tree, where both jars are included, and then 2. exclude the latter one

Comment: you get the maven dependencies tree via `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 6):

It is a conflict. Run the command

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=log4j-to-slf4j
```

Check from where you import that dependency and exclude it.

Reason is `log4j` is an API. You must include in your project an implementation for that API to work. Both `log4j-slf4j-impl` and `log4j-to-slf4j` are implementations for `log4j` API. When you include multiple implementations conflicts arise.